# How to zip specified folders with Command Line

Tags: .net, windows, command-line, backup, zip

Could you people tell me how to zip specified files into same Zip file. Let me tell how my folders are filled :

- A task scheduler have backups of my databases and save them into a file daily. It creates 4 database backup daily which means there will be 4 more files daily. So I need to zip newly created backups into same zip file (of course it differs from previous day zip file, the zip file will be created for that day for newly created backup files) and I need to do it automatically. Well I know how to make it automatic. I can use Windows task scheduler to automate things.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok... So, you're on Windows. Do you want to write a batch file? Power Shell script? C# program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) - it was originally produced as a library for use by programmers but the sample apps built on and shipped with the library have become very useful in their own right.

One of the "samples" is called zipit.exe - a console tool.  Specify a non-existent zipfile to create a new one, or specify an existing zipfile to update it.

```
zipit.exe ZipArchive.zip  c:\data\folder1
```

You can specify one or more filenames, directories, or a logical expression that describes which files to include.  For the expressions:

- `name = *.jpg`
  any .jpg file.
- `mtime > 07/01/2009`
  any file with a *last modified time* after midnight on 1 July 2009. There is also ctime and atime for created time and accessed time.
- `ctime > 07/01/2009:07:53:00`
  any file with a *created time* after 7:53am on 1 July 2009.
- `size > 320mb`
  any file with a size over 320mb.  You can use **kb** or **gb**, too.  Or omit the characters for a size in bytes. And you can use < or = as operations.
- `attr != H`
  any file that does not have the Hidden attribute set. Other attributes include S=system, R=Readonly, A=Archive.  Of course you can test that the attribute is ON as well (using = instead of !=).
- `attr != H and size > 320mb`
  include the files that satisfy both conditions.  You can also use OR as a conjuction. Use parens to group complex expressions.
- `name = *.jpg or name = *.gif`
  include the files that satisfy one or the other condition.
- `(name = *.jpg) or (name = *.gif)`
  same as above.
- `(mtime >= 07/01/2009) and (mtime < 07/02/2009)`
  any file modified on July 1st.  From midnight to midnight.
- `(name = *.jpg) AND (mtime >= 07/01/2009) and (mtime < 07/02/2009)`
  any .jpg file modified on July 1st.
- `(name = *.jpg) and (size >= 100kb) and (mtime >= 07/01/2009) and (mtime < 07/02/2009)`
  any .jpg file, 100kb or more in size, modified on July 1st.

With other options on the zipit.exe tool, you can also:

- specify whether you want to traverse reparse points (like symlinks or junctions, eg "My Music").
- recurse directories or not (default is NOT)
- encrypt the zip with AES or with "regular" zip encryption
- specify a segment size to produce a spanned or segmented zip file.
- produce a self-extracting archive

Examples:

`zipit.exe Archive.zip -D c:\project1 -r+  "(name = *.xlsx) and (mtime >= 07/01/2009) and (mtime < 07/31/2009)"`

- Produce a file, Archive.zip, that contains all the .xslx files in the c:\project1 directory hierarchy, that were modified in July.

`zipit.exe Unpack.exe -sfx w -D project2 -r+  "(name = *.pdf) and (size > 100kb)"`

- Produce a self-extracting GUI exe, named Unpack.exe, that contains all the .pdf files in the project2 directory hierarchy, that are larger than 100k in size.

---

DotNetZip is free.

All these features are available in the .NET interface of the library, too.  And there's a GUI tool, too.

Answer (score 12):

I use the open source program [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) with a command line like:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a My.zip MyFileOrFolder
```

If you're using an NTFS partition, it might also solve your issue to have Windows automatically compress the folder your backup files are in (right click on your folder, select Properties, Advanced, and click Compress contents to secure data).

Comment: nice answer, but it may be slightly better to use 7za.exe from the same package than 7z.exe, because 7z.exe uses other files from the folder it was installed to, whereas 7za.exe can work standalone, without looking into PATH variable to find the remaining files

Comment: @Dmityugov: Thanks, good to know.  I use 7z.exe regularly, but I guess my path is set appropriately.

Comment: I am using 7z.exe and not having any issues, even though I have not added its folder to my PATH

Comment: In fact, I don't see any 7za.exe... maybe the latest version eliminates this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've abandoned WinZip in favor of [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) because it's fast, free, efficient, and available for both Windows and Linux.

If you're a WinZip fan, take a look at the WinZip command-line support add-on: http://winzip.com/prodpagecl.htm

You can archive as many files or directories as your Windows command line will allow:

```
wzzip archive.zip dir1 dir2 dir3 ...
```

Comment: Well, actually I am neither fan of Winzip nor Winrar. I am currently using 7-Zip but I didn't know I could do such things with 7Zip :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can download GNU zip for Windows at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zip.htm.  If you want to got the whole UNIX command line route, zip is available with http://www.cygwin.com/.

The man page gives this example that seems to address your problem, there are many other command-line options as well:

For  example,  if  foo.zip  exists  and  contains  foo/file1  and
   foo/file2, and the directory foo contains the files foo/file1 and foo/file3, then:

```
      zip -r foo.zip foo
```

or more concisely

```
      zip -r foo foo
```

will  replace  foo/file1  in  foo.zip  and  add  foo/file3 to foo.zip.  After this,
   foo.zip contains foo/file1, foo/file2, and foo/file3, with foo/file2 unchanged from
   before.

Answer (score 1):

Look into an old program called PKZIP.  I believe you can also do this with WinZip and 7Zip.

Comment: yes for WinZip - it has a "wzcline" addon for adding wzzip.exe and wzunzip.exe commands to your command line. Zipping a folder is `wzzip -a -ex -r -p (zipname) (folder name)` - the key is -r = recursive and -p = include path information