# How to create ZIP files with specific encoding

Tags: windows, linux, encoding, zip, character-encoding

On my Linux server I have some files with accented names (test-éàïù.zip).
When I add them to a new ZIP file using 7zip command-line tool, the charset/encoding information is not saved and when opened on a Windows computer, the archive does not correctly display filenames.
I know that 7zip creates Zip V1.0 archives, not 2.0. Maybe the charset is limited to MSDos charset ?
How could I specify an encoding using 7zip or another zip tool, in order to get portable archives?

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 11):

This *is* a superuser question, BUT...

ZIP uses a default codepage of IBM437. There is the possibility to use UTF-8, but not all zip tools and libraries support that. Some zip tools will do arbitrary code pages, even though the zip spec allows only IBM437 or UTF-8. I think WinRar is one such tool.

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) does encoding.  It will do UTF-8 or an arbitrary code page.  if you're writing an app, there is a .NET library.  If you are running from a script, there are command line tools. Either way, DotNetZip requires .NET. You will need Mono to run it on Linux.

example for the command line:

```
zipit.exe Olivier.zip -cp 860 test-éàïù.txt
```

(to use the 860 codepage) I'm not sure that Windows Explorer correctly handles zipfiles with alternate encoding for the filenames within the zips.

See [How to zip specified folders with Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412051/how-to-zip-specified-folders-with-command-line/1424614#1424614) for more info on that zipit.exe tool.

Answer (score 3):

Create a ZIP file using specified code page:

```
7z a -mcp=<code_page> -tzip <archive_name> <file_names>...
```

Extract files from a ZIP file using specified code page:

```
7z x -mcp=<code_page> <archive_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know that 7zip creates Zip V1.0 archives, not 2.0.

I couldn't work out how to use 7zip to create a zip v1.0 archive.

You can create version 1 ZIP archives using Info-Zip’s zip 1.1, which is still available (download from the FTP http://infozip.sourceforge.net/Zip.html#Downloads). You’ll need to build it from source (make sysv on a Linux system); then you’ll be able to use the newly-built zip to create old-format archives:

```
]# ./zip filename.zip file1 file2 file3
]# file filename.zip 
]# filename.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```